# Fokker--Planck equation - naming a vector field

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, terminology, complex-systems, stochastic-processes

A Fokker Planck equation for the prob. density $\rho$ may be written in the form of a continuity equation
$$\frac{\partial \rho(x,t)}{\partial t} = - \nabla \cdot \left[  g(x,t)  \rho(x,t) \right].$$

The term $$   \left[  g(x,t)  \rho(x,t) \right] $$ is often called the **probability current** or the probability flux.

I was wondering whether there is a name for the term **$$ g(x,t) .$$** It is a vector field, but is there some more specific or descriptive characterisation for this term?

Answer (score 3):

It is called the **drift** term (here denoted as $\mu(X_t, t)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation. You have written the form with zero **diffusion** term,  more generally:
$$
\frac{\partial\rho(x,t)}{\partial t} = -\nabla [g(x, t) \rho(x,t)] + \nabla [D(x,t) \nabla p(x,t)]
$$
Where $D = D_{ij}$ is the **diffusion tensor**.

Comment: Ohh yes thank you!
I know that it is the drift of the associated SDE, but can I also call it velocity field?
I would like to have a term that is more related to the dynamics of the underlying system and depart from the terms that connect it to the SDE

Comment: @ii.iiii, i wouldn't say so in general, it the case of constant in space and time field, this does really resemble the advection equation : $$\partial_t \rho = -g \nabla \rho$$, and $g$ would be a speed of wave, but in general, there is a term $$ (\nabla g) \rho$$, which would make it not like the wave equation with coordinate and time-dependent velocity.

Comment: Thank you!
It seems that this can be called **flow velocity vector field** according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation#Fluid_dynamics
So I will name it **time-dependent flow velocity vector field**.
Hope people will accept it :)